# Why is my returning bitmap not returning properly?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I'm passing an image in to this method and fading the right edge of it, it was working and suddenly doesn't any more. It's returning the bitmap that i'm passing in to it, but not keeping the modified pixels, they come back original. Where am i going wrong?

```
private Bitmap fadedEdge(Bitmap bmp)
{
    //img.Save("i.bmp");
    //Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)img;
    int howfartofade = bmp.Width / 4;
    int i = 0;
    if (howfartofade > 255) i = howfartofade / 255;
    else i = 255 / howfartofade;
    if (i == 0) i = 1;
    int alp = 255;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x = bmp.Width - howfartofade; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    {
        if (howfartofade > 255)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == i + 1)
            {
                alp -= 1;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alp -= i;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            if (alp >= 0)
            {
                Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                clr = Color.FromArgb(alp, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
            }
            else
            {
                Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                clr = Color.FromArgb(0, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
            }
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `bmp`? It's passed in as a parameter, and `Bitmap` is a reference type (a class).

Comment: Does your Bitmap object have an alpha channel? Check bmp.PixelFormat.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Stupid me. I changed it to pass in an image and return an image, and created a new bitmap from the image being passed in to it.

```
private Image fadedEdge(Image input)
    {
        //img.Save("i.bmp");
        //Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)img;
        Bitmap output = new Bitmap(input);
        int howfartofade = input.Width / 8;
        int i = 0;
        if (howfartofade > 255) i = howfartofade / 255;
        else i = (255 / howfartofade) + 1;
        if (i == 0) i = 1;
        int alp = 255;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = input.Width - howfartofade; x < input.Width; x++)
        {
            if (howfartofade > 255)
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter == i + 1)
                {
                    alp -= 1;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alp -= (i);
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < input.Height; y++)
            {
                if (alp >= 0)
                {
                    Color clr = output.GetPixel(x, y);
                    clr = Color.FromArgb(alp, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
                    output.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
                }
                else
                {
                    Color clr = output.GetPixel(x, y);
                    clr = Color.FromArgb(0, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
                    output.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```